# Libgdx: draw actors in specific rectangle

Tags: android, libgdx, drawing

I tried to draw a `Group` of Actors in a stage, but I need to draw them only in a specific area of the stage.

For example suppose that I divided the stage in 2 parts(left and right), then I want to draw some actors only in the left part of the stage, so if one of them go to the right it won't be drawn.

So far, I tried to use `setCullingArea` method but Actors disappear suddenly, I want to draw a part of an actor if it is in the limit.

In other words I'm looking for a kind of mask area which a `Group` is drawn.

Thanks.

Comment: Well you can do the simple collision detection and check if your actor (Rectangle) right most touches the center of screen then don't let it draw!

Comment: But my problem is to draw a part of an actor if it is the limit, for example if my actor is a circle, when it is in the middle of the screen I want to draw a half of a circle.

Comment: You need to check how can you setup two viewports in a single screen and then Orthographic Camera should do the trick.

Comment: Try asking it there also http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with scissors, which clip the drawing to a specific area of the screen.

```
Rectangle leftSide;
Rectangle rightSide;

//...

public void resize(int width, int height){
    //...

    leftSide = new Rectangle(0,0,width/2, height);
    rightSide = new Rectangle(width/2, 0, width/2, height);

}

public void render(){
    //...

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glScissor((int)leftSide.x, (int)leftSide.y, (int)leftSide.width, (int)leftSide.height);

    //Draw stage with left side actors (set right group invisible)
    //...

    Gdx.gl.glScissor((int)rightSide.x, (int)rightSide.y, (int)rightSide.width, (int)rightSide.height);

    //Draw stage with right side actors (set left group invisible)
    //...

    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    //...
}
```

If you have other actors that need to stretch across the boundary, you could draw those first before enabling scissoring, and then set them invisible.